# Reduce bump by distance to camera

Tags: rendering, camera, bump

I'm trying to reduce bump by distance to camera and finally I get a mess of nodes and I got lost. I post a picture of what I got, but just for reference, please, no laughs ;)

[image]

Could you help me how to get it? Thanks!

EDIT: That animated positions at mapping is because it's a kind of sea simulation

Comment: Hi :). You want to decrease the Displacement the further it is from camera?

Comment: Exactly, it dissapears if farther.

Comment: There should be a [Displacement](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/displacement.html) node between the last *MixRGB* and the *Material Output* node. It works similar to the *Bump* and *Normal Map* nodes that you need for the *Normal* input slot of the *Principled BSDF*. The *Displacement* node has a *Scale* value which controls the strength of the bumps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I accomplished this with a spherical gradient.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see your answer :)

Answer (score 5):

You can target the camera in texture coordinate node.

1. Use Object coordinates and target the camera
2. Add *Vector Math > Length* + *ColorRamp* to control the falloff
3. Multiply your textures by the result

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this is *Camera Data* -> *View Z Depth* or *View Distance*.

The values output by this are completely unusable without some modification, so you need to make judicious use of the *Map Range* node.

Here I'm taking the data from roughly the start distance of my object to the end distance, and remapping to a range of 1-0.  We apply that to the *Strength* input of the *Normal Map* node so that the close end has full strength bump and fades to 0 at the far end.

[image]